# Determining Fling Direction

Tags: android, android-gesture

I'm using a `GestureDetector` to have `onFling()` called.  It seems to be correctly detecting my flings as it triggers a Log message I created.  I'm trying to determine the direction of the fling, but am running into problems.  The x values are the same for both `MotionEvent` objects passed into the `onFling()` method so I cannot determine the direction.  For example, I get:

```
08-05 16:36:08.679: DEBUG/mView(14616): fling2: 131.0 131.0
```

When I do:

```
Log.d("mView", "fling2: " + e1.getX() + " " + e2.getX());
```

When performing the fling, I am only moving my finger horizontal so this makes no sense to me.  What could be going wrong here?

Comment: What about `Y`? Does it changes?

Comment: @user1873880 The Y does change.  If I make a similar debug log I get `fling3: 775.0 599.0` when performing a diagonal fling, but still `fling2: 167.0 167.0` for the X.

Comment: @trevor-e droidQuery should really help you. The creator is phil brown, and he has a stack overflow account also. If you have anymore questions about droidQuery, feel free to ask with the droidQuery tag so me or him can easily find your question.

Answer (score 2):

You can use droidQuery: https://github.com/phil-brown/droidQuery. It will really simplify your code and make it easy to use. Here is all you need to put in your activities onCreate():

```
//global variables
private boolean isSwiping = false;
private SwipeDetector.Direction swipeDirection = null;
private View v;//set to the parent layout of the fragments.

//swipe-handling code
$.with(v).swipe(new Function() {
    @Override
    public void invoke($ droidQuery, Object... params) {
        if (params[0] == SwipeDetector.Direction.START)
            isSwiping = true;
        else if (params[0] == SwipeDetector.Direction.STOP) {
            if (isSwiping) {
                isSwiping = false;
                if (swipeDirection != null) {
                    switch(swipeDirection) {
                        case DOWN :
                            //TODO: Down swipe complete, so do something
                            break; 
                        case UP :
                            //TODO: Up swipe complete, so do something
                            break; 
                        case LEFT :
                            //TODO: Left swipe complete, so do something
                            break; 
                        case RIGHT :
                            //TODO: Right swipe complete, so do something (such as):
                            day++;
                            Fragment1 rightFragment = new Fragment1();
                            Bundle args = new Bundle();
                            args.putInt("day", day);
                            rightFragment.setArguments(args);

                            android.support.v4.app.FragmentTransaction transaction = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
                            transaction.replace(R.id.fragment_container, rightFragment);
                            transaction.addToBackStack(null);
                            transaction.commit();
                            break; 
                        default :
                            break; 
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        else {
            swipeDirection = (SwipeDetector.Direction) params[0];
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: Sorry, this library looks nice, but it is not what I need.  I'm thinking my problem is more bug related.