# Understanding OnGestureListener for swipe

Tags: android

I am not able to understand why this code doesnot show any Toast.
I have implemented OnGestureListener interface and trying to display some toast when user 
swipe over the activity.
it means onFling method must be called but I am not receiving any toast.
Please help me understand the problem.

```
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.view.GestureDetector.OnGestureListener;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MotionEvent;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class MainActivity extends Activity implements OnGestureListener {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onDown(MotionEvent e) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    Toast.makeText(this,"onDown",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    return false;
}

@Override
public boolean onFling(MotionEvent e1, MotionEvent e2, float velocityX,
        float velocityY) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    Toast.makeText(this,"Swipe to Explore the Happiness Path",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    return false;
}

@Override
public void onLongPress(MotionEvent e) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    Toast.makeText(this,"onLongPress",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

}

@Override
public boolean onScroll(MotionEvent e1, MotionEvent e2, float distanceX,
        float distanceY) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return false;
}

@Override
public void onShowPress(MotionEvent e) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}

@Override
public boolean onSingleTapUp(MotionEvent e) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub`enter code here`
    return false;
}
```

}

Comment: You have to implement it using `GestureDetector` then it will detected only.

Comment: You can also use the [droidQuery](http://bit.ly/droidquery) library to easily handle swipe events. See [this post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18067336/determining-fling-direction) for a great example.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> A GestureDetector is an Android class that can take motion events, do
>   some mathematical magic to determine what they are, and then delegate
>   calls to a GestureListener object as specific gesture or other motion
>   callbacks. The GestureListener object, a class we implement, receives
>   these calls for specific gestures that the GestureDetector recognizes
>   and allows us to react to them as we see fit (in this case, to move a
>   graphic around within our PlayAreaView). Although the GestureDetector
>   handles the detection of certain motions, it doesn’t do anything
>   specific with them nor does it handle all types of gestures.

Try out as below add the GestureDetector and implement `onTouch` event to detect the touch of screen :

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity implements OnGestureListener {

private GestureDetector gDetector;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
gDetector = new GestureDetector(this);
}
 @Override
public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent me) {
    return gDetector.onTouchEvent(me);
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onDown(MotionEvent e) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    Toast.makeText(this,"onDown",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    return false;
}

@Override
public boolean onFling(MotionEvent e1, MotionEvent e2, float velocityX,
        float velocityY) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    Toast.makeText(this,"Swipe to Explore the Happiness Path",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    return false;
}

@Override
public void onLongPress(MotionEvent e) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    Toast.makeText(this,"onLongPress",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

}

@Override
public boolean onScroll(MotionEvent e1, MotionEvent e2, float distanceX,
        float distanceY) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return false;
}

@Override
public void onShowPress(MotionEvent e) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}

@Override
public boolean onSingleTapUp(MotionEvent e) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub`enter code here`
    return false;
}
}
```

To understand more [GestureDetector](http://mobile.tutsplus.com/tutorials/android/android-gesture/)